How to see my lock screens when connected to my monitor via USB-C?
I have an Android phone with a broken screen. When I try and unlock it, while attached to my monitor via USB-C, all I can see is a lock icon floating around. I roughly guess where the dots are for the pattern and usually I can get it unlocked.
Now, there are also some apps that I use that ask me to enter a password. Again, the screen goes black and I cannot see what I am doing. I've tried entering the password with the keyboard but no luck. I imagine this is some type of security feature doing this.
Is there a setting to turn that off so I can see these screens?

What phone model do you use? For external monitors there are different modes implemented by the manufacturer like DEX mode from Samsung. Therefore behavior may be different based on what phone you use. Anyway even if you don't see the login screen you can try to enter your password blindly. If you have access to a second phone you can use it for practicing.

It's a Solana SAGA. You won't find much info. My understanding it is a re-branded OSOM OV1. I've tried blind and with a keyboard. No luck.
